# How to use `ClassTag` and type comparison operator, `<:` at the same time?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-reflect, context-bound

I have the following class defined,

```
class FixedLengthQueue[T<:Hashable](maxLength: Int) {
    private val _outdated = ArrayBuffer.empty[T]
    def outdated: Array[T] = {
      val result = _outdated.toArray[T]
      _outdated.clear()
      result
    }
  }
```

However, at runtime, it reports `error: No ClassTag available for T`.
What is the syntax for defining a type as a ClassTag and using `<:` at the same time?

Comment: `class FixedLengthQueue[T <: Hashable : ClassTag]`, or add an implicit parameter in the end

Comment: *"However, at runtime, it reports `error: No ClassTag available for T`"* Hardly this occurs at runtime. "No ClassTag available" is a compile-time error.